# Adding an OR statement within a boolean

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

The following code gives me 4 different boolean options.

```
'Yes
b1 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And _
          ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
          ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2"))
'No
b2 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
          ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2"))

'Yes/No
b3 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
          ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
          Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2"))
'Yes/Yes
b4 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And _
         ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
         ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
         Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2"))
```

Is it possible to add an OR to B3 and B4 like so...

```
'Yes/No
b3 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
          ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
          Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2") 
          OR
          Abs(ds.Cells(x, 83) - ds.Cells(x, 93)) >= fs.Range("F2"))
```

Comment: Yes, wrap the two arguments with the OR in their own `()`

Comment: Not sure why you use `CBool` as well. The result of each statement is already a boolean.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just try it than post here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do what you are asking. Let me also suggest a few adjustments for optimization.

This comparison appears several times in the code:

```
'No
b2 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
           ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2"))
```

So do that assignment first. Once assigned, it can be reused. For example:

```
'Yes
b1 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And _
           ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
           ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2"))
```

Becomes:

```
'Yes
b1 = CBool(ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And b2)
```

And b3 becomes:

```
'Yes/No
b3 = CBool(b2 And Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2"))
```

Finally, b4 is just b1 with another condition, so it becomes:

```
'Yes/Yes
b4 = CBool(b1 And Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2"))
```

Now, if both b3 and b4 are going to have the same conditions added, you could add a fifth variable b5 that is just:

```
b5 = Abs(ds.Cells(x, 83) - ds.Cells(x, 93)) >= fs.Range("F2")
```

The new `OR` would look like this:

```
b3 = b2 AND Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2") And b5
```

As BigBen pointed out, the CBool isn't necessary. As Scott Craner pointed out, be careful about parentheses. `A And B And C Or D` is not the same as `(A And B) And (C Or D)`. Order of precedence for logical operators says that `A And B And C Or D` will be evaluated as `(A And B And C) Or D`. Make sure that's what you want.

### Summary

I have made changes to your code to aid some future developer with understanding. I used your variable names, but I don't like them. It would be better to be more descriptive.

```
' No
b2 = ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
     ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2")

' Yes
b1 = b2 And ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1")

diff1 = Abs(ds.Cells(x, 82) - ds.Cells(x, 92)) >= fs.Range("F2")
diff2 = Abs(ds.Cells(x, 83) - ds.Cells(x, 93)) >= fs.Range("F2") 

' Yes/No
b3 = b2 And diff1 Or diff2  ' Possibly should be b2 And (diff1 Or diff2)

' Yes/Yes
b4 = b1 And diff1 Or diff2  ' Possibly should be b1 And (diff1 Or diff2)
```

Hope that gets you on your way.

Comment: Many thanks. In fact it is the bracketed version i needed

Comment: I'm glad it helped.